# Search a word in the files in output

Tags: grep

When I run the following command :

```
find loanwolf/ -name '*.html' -exec grep --color -rn 'loanwolf_tags' {} +
```

it gives me some files in output. I'd like to search a new word in the files in output, but I can't use `grep` to do such thing I figure. How could I do such thing?

Comment: Why are you using grep-r with find? Find already recurses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two grep

`-exec` give a true or false, so

```
find .. -exec grep foo {} \; -exec grep bar {} \;
```

won't search for `bar` in a file if `foo` isn't found.

`\;` is old school (you need to escape `;`), `+` is new school.

Comment: What is the difference between `+` and `\;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like as shown to get the results :

```
find loanwolf/. -type f -name '*.html' -exec grep -lHZ loanwolf_tags {} + |
xargs -r -0 grep -lH new_word
```

Here what we are doing is looking at regular files with extension html, we feed a bunch of them to grep and look for loanwolf_tags string in these. The `-l` option will display the filenames in which such string are found and passed forward to `xargs` after appending the filenames with null `\0`.

The `xargs` will receive these filenames and split them on the null character thereby recovering all manner of filenames. Then xargs will a bunch of these filenames and feed them to `grep` and look for new_word and display the file-names that match.